# Loading multiple csv files into a single dataFrame but with different columns names

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have 100 csv files, I want to load these multiple files into a single data frame, each of these files have same number of columns but the column names are different, this is what I have tried so far
any help would be much appreciated

```
 setwd("F:/Task sheet/NanoSniff_Data")
file_names <- dir("F:/Task sheet/NanoSniff_Data") 

my_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

Comment: You could set the column names to be identical using `colnames`.

Comment: what if you do not read the header of your files with `header = FALSE`  and `skip = 1` ? 
First line of your file containing colnames won't be read, and so some default ones will be created, same for every data.frame. `rbind` should work then

Comment: or your could put the same column names after reading csv, then do `rbind`. do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Titolondon I tried using your suggestion, yet left with an error ; this has been mentioned in my another post,here's the link                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277222/error-while-reading-multiple-csv-files-without-header

Comment: I think you found your answer with sapply. I was suggesting `my_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv, header = F, skip = 1))`. Should not give an error.

Comment: @Titolondon yes it did worked!! both the solutions worked, Thanks alot!